# Blender's property definition: is this standard Python type annotation?

Tags: python, scripting, properties

According to Blender's [doc](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html), this is how to define properties:

```
class OBJECT_OT_property_example(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.property_example"
    bl_label = "Property Example"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    my_float: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Some Floating Point")
    my_bool: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Toggle Option")
    my_string: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="String Value")

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report(
            {'INFO'}, 'F: %.2f  B: %s  S: %r' %
            (self.my_float, self.my_bool, self.my_string)
        )
        print('My float:', self.my_float)
        print('My bool:', self.my_bool)
        print('My string:', self.my_string)
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

I don't understand this line:

```
my_float: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Some Floating Point")
```

Afaik, this is Python's type annotation syntax. But `bpy.props.FloatProperty` should be a type already, and `bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Some Floating Point")` would create an instance. Why can it be used as a type too? Is this a part of standard Python, and if so, how it actually works?

Comment: `bpy.props.FooProperty()` is a method used for annotating a class with property definitions, that when registered build an operator with props  akin to (old style for example sake) `Foo.prop = property(setter, getter)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct [PEP 526 -- Syntax for Variable Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) describes the variable annotation using the colon character that was added to Python version 3.6.

Although 526 never makes it explicit, annotations are expressions that can be evaluated.  See [Runtime Effects of Type Annotation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#runtime-effects-of-type-annotations) in 526.

The various property functions such as [`bpy.props.FloatProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.FloatProperty) are functions that are evaluated to return "a new SOME_TYPE property definition."

Unfortunately, the various property functions are written in C.  Here's [FloatProperty](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/python/intern/bpy_props.c#L2709).  The trick is that when the C code recognizes a call to `bpy.props.FloatProperty` it adds code that will be called when you register the class containing the property.

But the result of this 'magic' is an ordinary Python variable that Blender knows some extra things about.