# Python error in dialogue pop-up script

Tags: python

I'm following a tutorial on how to make a pop-up box for a cube that lets you change the scale: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3C6wVPVrPtM

I downloaded the author's code and there are no errors when running the script. When I click the cube button I'm only getting a dialogue box with "ok" and clicking that returns an error as shown in the screenshot. What's wrong and how do I do fix it?

[image]

Comment: Since a few versions you must define operator properties with `:` (annotations), not `=` (declaration). IE : replace `text = StringProperty(...)` with `text: StringProperty(...)`

Comment: lines 114 and 115

Comment: I see. That was a dumb change. Thank you

Comment: Here's an explanation if you're interested https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/229707/86891